# PHP логическая задача

Tags: php, массивы, функции, циклы

У меня есть переменная $amount_days в которой находится количество дней от 1 до 7.

Как присвоить всем числам до $amount_days: текст "gift__item-previous", числу в $amount_days: "gift__item-today", а $amount_days + 1: "gift__item-next"?

Должен получится массив по типу:

```
$class_gift = [1 => 'gift__item-previous', 2 => 'gift__item-previous', 3 => 'gift__item-previous', 4 => 'gift__item-today', 5 => 'gift__item-next', 6 => '', 7 => ''];
```

Ну или если вам будет по проще можно и так:

```
$class_gift = ['gift__item-previous', 'gift__item-previous', 'gift__item-previous', 'gift__item-today', 'gift__item-next', '', ''];
```

Эти пример если $amount_days = 4

Можно конечно 7 if'ов забабахать, но мне кажется есть вариант по лучше и по проще. Если понадобится дополнительная информация спрашивайте в комментариях.

В if'ах это выглядело примерно так:

```
if ($amount_days = 1) {
    $class_gift = ['gift__item-today', 'gift__item-next', '', '', '', '', ''];
} elseif ($amount_days = 2) {
    $class_gift = ['gift__item-previous', 'gift__item-today', 'gift__item-next', '', '', '', ''];
} elseif ($amount_days = 3) {
    $class_gift = ['gift__item-previous', 'gift__item-previous', 'gift__item-today', 'gift__item-next', '', '', ''];
} elseif ($amount_days = 4) {
    $class_gift = ['gift__item-previous', 'gift__item-previous', 'gift__item-previous', 'gift__item-today', 'gift__item-next', '', ''];
} elseif ($amount_days = 5) {
    $class_gift = ['gift__item-previous', 'gift__item-previous', 'gift__item-previous', 'gift__item-previous', 'gift__item-today', 'gift__item-next', ''];
} elseif ($amount_days = 6) {
    $class_gift = ['gift__item-previous', 'gift__item-previous', 'gift__item-previous', 'gift__item-previous', 'gift__item-previous', 'gift__item-today', 'gift__item-next'];
} elseif ($amount_days = 7) {
    $class_gift = ['gift__item-previous', 'gift__item-previous', 'gift__item-previous', 'gift__item-previous', 'gift__item-previous', 'gift__item-previous', 'gift__item-today'];
}
```

*(Для тех кто не понял $amount_days может быть 3, 2, 6, 1. Держите в голове что $amount_days = rand(1, 7); что легче было понять)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[array_fill](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-fill.php) отлично справляется с вашей логической задачей

```
$class_gift = array_fill(1, $amount_days-1, 'gift__item-previous') 
              + [$amount_days => 'gift__item-today'] 
              + array_fill($amount_days+1, 7 - $amount_days, '');
print_r($class_gift);
```

вот для 5:

```
array (
  1 => 'gift__item-previous',
  2 => 'gift__item-previous',
  3 => 'gift__item-previous',
  4 => 'gift__item-previous',
  5 => 'gift__item-today',
  6 => '',
  7 => '',
)
```

---

добавим забытый next

```
$class_gift = array_fill(1, $amount_days-1, 'gift__item-previous') 
+ [$amount_days => 'gift__item-today'] 
+ array_fill($amount_days+1, $amount_days < 7 ? 1 : 0, 'gift__item-next')
+ array_fill($amount_days+2, max(0, 7 - $amount_days - 1), '');
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение, вы только про gift__item-next забыли но это я сам уже до делаю, можете пояснить что делает эта строка `+ array_fill($amount_days+1, 7 - $amount_days, '');`

Comment: добавляет ваши пустые элементы в конец массива до 7

Comment: дополнил ответ - дообавил next

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли

Comment: Есть вопрос один, поможете? У меня есть переменная $gift_status как сделать так чтобы если она равна 1 то вместо gift__item-today, было gift__item-next

Comment: Извините уже додумался сам `$class_gift = array_fill(1, $amount_days - 1, 'gift__item-previous')
 + [$amount_days => (($gift_status == 0) ? 'gift__item-today' : 'gift__item-next')]
 + array_fill($amount_days + 2, max(0, 7 - $amount_days - 1), '');`